# Как заливать изменения с worktree - git

Tags: git, github

У меня была одна ветка `Develop`, мне нужно что бы рядом с текущей папкой репозитория, была еще одна, которая бы отслеживалась и её изменения заливались в ветку `Develop_Install`. Я погуглил, пишут что через worktree. Пишу: `git worktree add -b Develop_Install ..\Develop_Install` - оно создало ветку и создало папку рядом с таким же содержимым. Теперь вопрос, как отслеживать и заливать изменения?

И еще, можно ли сделать это через `GitHub Desktop`? Если да, то как?

Comment: Так же как и везде: `git add`, `git commit` и т.п.

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, только что смотрел в чем же может быть проблема, оказывается нужно перейти в ту папку и от туда делать `git ...` :)

Comment: Логично, чёрт побери…

Comment: @AlexeyTen Согласен, тупанул :)

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался. Я пробывал переключится на `worktree` и закомитить из папки `Develop`, когда нужно было перейти в папку `Develop_Install` и от туда писать `git ...`.